# SQLite freezing android application on entry and eventual crash

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to create a basic SQLite activity within my app in which users can write, save and delete memos. on the initial run I could open the activity and write a memo in but once the add button was pressed the application froze and eventually crashed out, on follow up runs I get the freeze on attempting to launch the activity. the android moniter is giving me a stream of

> 04-09 17:16:51.171 24190-24196/com.test.test.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.236ms

errors. Any ideas?

MyDbHandler class

```
package com.test.test.app;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
public class MyDbHandler  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Memos.db";
    public static final String TABLE_MEMOS = "Memos";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LYRICS = "lyrics";

    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMOS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_LYRICS + " TEXT" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_MEMOS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //add a new row to the database
    public void addLyric(Memos lyrics) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_LYRICS, lyrics.get_lyrics());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_MEMOS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    //delete product from database
    public void deleteLyrics (String lyrics){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_MEMOS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LYRICS + "=\"" + lyrics + "\";");
    }


    //print out database as string
    public String databaseToString(){
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEMOS + " WHERE 1";

        //cursor point to result
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //first row
        c.moveToFirst();

       while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lyrics"))!= null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lyrics"));
                dbString += "\n";
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
     }
```

MemoActivity class

```
package com.test.test.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.test.test.app.MyDbHandler;

public class MemoActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText uInput;
    TextView uText;
    MyDbHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_memo);
        uInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uInput);
        uText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uText);
        dbHandler = new MyDbHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked(View view){
        Memos lyrics = new Memos(uInput.getText().toString());
        dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void deleteButtonClicked(View view){
        String inputText = uInput.getText().toString();
        dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputText);
        printDatabase();
    }

    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        uText.setText(dbString);
        uInput.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have your own reasons for taking the higher road on data storage and databases in general but have you considered tools like Realm for Android?

Comment: @Eenvincible had never heard of it. thank you will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `c.moveToNext();` into your code, like this:

```
 while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lyrics"))!= null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lyrics"));
                dbString += "\n";
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();        
        }
```

If you don't call `moveToNext()` in the `while`, the `isAfterLast()` will never be *true* so you end up with ever lasting loop and, out of memory exception as the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help but im currently getting cannot resolve method on moveNext

Comment: @LJAM, sorry it is moveToNext();